# How can I set up local server for version control?

Tags: git

I want to push my code from my laptop to another computer which acts as local server in our network. How can i do that with git so that there is always backup of my work in the local server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is ro use a simple shared folder, accessible from your computer, and setup on the other computer: Git supports the "**[local protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#Local-Protocol)**".
In that case, no need for a server (a listener like  Apache or SSH).
But there would not be any authentication or authorization.

You need to create a bare (no working tree) empty repo on your remote server

```
git init --bare /path/to/myrepo.git
```

Then you your local repo:

```
cd /path/to/my/local/repo
git remote add origin //shared_folder/path/to/myrepo.git
git push -u origin master
...
git pull
```

(the `.git` is a naming convention for bare repos root folder)

The second simplest way is, if you can ssh to your remote server, to reference your remote Git repo that way:

```
git remote add origin <useraccount>@<remoteServerIP>:/path/to/myrepo.git
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How are we suppose to pull code from the server to my local computer and push my code from local computer to the local server?

Comment: @PrajwalBati I have edited the answer to add the relevant commands.

Comment: Whenever i tried to pull from the remote repo, it shows error,
`fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`

Comment: That happens whenever the remote repo was done before the local one, with a different history. If you clone there remote repo and do your commits there, you will then be able to push, and pull.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to install GitLab https://about.gitlab.com/installation/, which also provides a handy web interface.

Comment: Gitlab is perhaps overkill for a first step (but excellent when more experienced with more needs). I recommend https://gogs.io/